# 2000 Mercury Sable instrument cluster and headlights do not turn off

Tags: electrical, instrument-cluster, sable

My 2000 Mercury Sable Premium LS (3.0L 24V Duratec V6) has an electrical issue:

When I remove the key from the ignition, the instrument cluster and headlights do not run off.  I can reach in at any time, regardless of key presence, and turn on the headlights or check the instrument cluster.

I manually turn off my headlights using the switch, but I fear the instrument cluster is draining my battery.  It was hard starting one morning, so I threw the charger on it when I got home and found that it was down to 60-70% capacity.

How can I fix this, or is this not a bug but instead a feature?

Comment: Are you talking about low beams, or the parking lights? Usually cars allow the parking lights to be left on, but the low beams turn off when the ignition is turned off.

Comment: Both of them could be turned on, I believe.  I will run outside and check now.

Comment: Both Parking lights and Low Beams can be turned on while the key is sitting in a drawer.

Comment: Could this be a bad/sticky relay?

Comment: It could, technically. If you know which relays are involved you can try pulling them to find the one turning off the lights and test it. Though it won't be the one triggered by the headlight switch, clearly. However first I'd make sure that this isn't normal behavior, some cars might do that. What about other electrics, such as power windows, radio, etc., do they turn off?

Comment: Radio turns off like it should.  I haven't checked power windows yet, but the 12V cigarette lighter outlet remains live, and in other cars I've found that the cigarette lighters and the windows are on the same circuit.  I'll go check now.

Comment: Windows do not work, neither do radio or blinkers.  Hazards work.

Comment: In that case everything else is in order. The lighter outlet might remain live, it does on some cars. You should consult other owners if their car does the same and check the involved relays.

Comment: Problem is I don't know anyone with this car...  Anyone here have this problem?